# Keep the conditional formatting even if cells used in formula is cleared

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I need to highlight Cells of column B That Contain Text from a List, column D.
I want to keep the highlighting/formatting of column B and remove column D. But when I clear column D, all the formatting gets deleted too. What is the workaround for this?

I'm using the first method provided [here](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-highlight-cells-that-contain-text-from-a-list/) to do the highlighting.

Tried copy pasting and paste special. Still when I delete column Formatting disappears.

Comment: Use VBA to apply the formatting. Conditional formatting won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that rules are very easy to break, but here's something you can try that don't seem to break any rules.

You can change text inside cells. If you need to add a row, add your data at the end of your table and re-sort it. If you need to delete a row, only remove the text/numbers, then re-sort the table.

This works for me when I have conditional formatting that's applied to columns, and I usually set the formatting for the whole column, eg. $F:$F. It should still work if you're formatting for a partial range, just make sure that when you're done adding/removing and resorting that all the data you want formatted is still within your original range parameters.

It's a huge frustration for me as well.

I hope this helps.